# facebook SDK, invite friends

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-invite, facebook-invite-friends

I am developing an app, and users will be able to log in with Facebook. They only can start using the app if a minimum of their Facebook friend are already using the app. If not, they have to wait until the minimum required number of friend use the app in order to use it. I want to allow them to invite their Facebook friends to join.
Also, I would like to know how I can make it happen?
Do I HAVE TO create a facebook canvas or is there any other ways I can make it works? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: _“They only can start using the app if a minimum of their Facebook friend are already using the app. If not, they have to wait until the minimum required number of friend use the app in order to use it”_ – I’m not sure whether that is allowed by FB Platform Policies …

Answer (score 2):

**https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app**

Games on Canvas: [App Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests)

Other Apps/Games: [Send](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog) Dialog or [Message](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#message-dialog) Dialog

Answer (score 0):

You can't access invitable_friends without enabling facebook canvas in your app's settings, but maybe app requests safisfy your needs? It will list friends (user needs to authorise reading friends list by app) and allow user to send them a notification in their mobile facebook app which will open an app or take user to app's page in App Store if they haven't installed your app yet.

Remember to enable deep linking, facebook SSO and provide App Store ID in platform settings for this work.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/